# "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed." When deserializing from file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following problem: When I start my app, Settings are loaded from a file, so deserialized, when this happens I got the following error:

`{"End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."} System.Exception {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}`

Serialization code:

```
using(FileStream write = new FileStream(SETTINGSPATH,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write)
{
  BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  formatter.Serialize(write,settings);
}
```

Deserialisation method:

```
using (FileStream read = new FileStream(SETTINGSPATH,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
  BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  read.Position = 0;
  settings = (Settings)formatter.Deserialize(read); // settings is declared as Settings object
}
```

Settings class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace Serie_Counter.Overkoepelend
{
public delegate void SelectedMoveOptionChanged(AutoMoveOption selectedOption, int checkInterval = 30 );

public delegate void EnableAutoMoveChanged(bool EnableAutoMove);

[Serializable]
public class Settings
{
    private string serieListSavePath;
    private bool autoStart;
    private bool enableRember;
    private bool closeWithMainForm;
    private int warningDelay;
    // moving options
    private bool enableAutoMove;
    private string rootFolder;
    private int checkInterval;
    private AutoMoveOption selectedMoveOption;

    public event SelectedMoveOptionChanged selectedMoveOptionChanged;
    public event EnableAutoMoveChanged enableAutoMoveChanged;

    #region Properties

    public string SerieListSavePath
    {
        get
        {
            return serieListSavePath;
        }
        set
        {
            serieListSavePath = value;
        }
    }

    public bool AutoStart
    {
        get
        {
            return autoStart;
        }
        set
        {
            autoStart = value;
        }
    }

    public bool EnableRember
    {
        get
        {
            return enableRember;
        }
        set
        {
            enableRember = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CloseWithMainForm
    {
        get
        {
            return closeWithMainForm;
        }
        set
        {
            closeWithMainForm = value;
        }
    }

    public int WarningDelay
    {
        get
        {
            return warningDelay;
        }
        set
        {
            warningDelay = value;
        }
    }

    public bool EnableAutoMove
    {
        get
        {
            return enableAutoMove;
        }
        set
        {
            enableAutoMove = value;
            if (enableAutoMove != null) enableAutoMoveChanged(value);
        }
    }

    public string RootFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return rootFolder;
        }
        set
        {
            rootFolder = value;
        }
    }

    public int CheckInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return checkInterval;
        }
        set
        {
            checkInterval = value;
        }
    }

    public AutoMoveOption SelectedMoveOption
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedMoveOption;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedMoveOption = value;
            selectedMoveOptionChanged(value, checkInterval);

        }
    }

    #endregion



    public Settings(string serieListSavePath)
    {
        this.serieListSavePath = serieListSavePath;
    }

    public Settings()
    {
        this.serieListSavePath = "series.xml";
        warningDelay = -1;
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void SetValuesOnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        selectedMoveOptionChanged = null;
        enableAutoMoveChanged = null;

    }
```

Does any one know why this happens ?

If you would like more info or code please check http://seriescounter.codeplex.com/

Greets
Thomas

EDIT: Could the problem be that the deserialization fails because I serialize the events to?
I just tested this by making sure the events are null when serialized. and so far the error didn't happen again.

http://seriescounter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/12646

Comment: Did you check if the file exists and not corrupted?

Comment: If you just a storing settings, then a rule of thumb is to use a readable format, like XML to save the settings.

Comment: Please post the code you use to serialize and save the settings. It's not easy to find in the link to codeplex that you posted. I suspect it might be missing a `Flush`. Also, you are not firing your `enableAutoMoveChanged` event correctly. You should first copy the event to a local variable `var ev=enableAutoMoveChanged;` then check if `ev` is not null, then fire it `ev(value);`

Comment: I check if the file exists

serialization code:
<code>
    using(FileStream write = new FileStream(SETTINGSPATH,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                    formatter.Serialize(write,settings);
                }
</code>
could it be I have the error because I serialize the events to?

Comment: I would serialize to a readable format (xml/json) and see what is wrong with the settings file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change set 12594 is your problem, you added the checkIntervalChanged event to the Settings class.  That added an otherwise invisible field to the class that gets serialized as well.  But now you have a problem with setting files that were saved with a previous version, the serialization data doesn't contain that field, the exception is the result.

You can rescue it like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Settings {
        [NonSerialized]
        private CheckIntervalChanged checkIntervalChangedBacking;

        public event CheckIntervalChanged CheckIntervalChanged {
            add { checkIntervalChangedBacking += value; }
            remove { checkIntervalChangedBacking -= value; }
        }
        // etc..
    }
```

The [NonSerialized] attribute now makes sure that the backing field doesn't get serialized.  You never want to serialize events anyway.

In general, you need to be careful with binary serialization, versioning is tricky to deal with.  Adding a field can and will instantly turn any stored data into junk.  There are good hints in the "[Version tolerant serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229752%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)" section in the MSDN library.

Comment: Added fields to a class shouldn't affect deserialization from an older version as the unknown fields will just be filled with their default values. Also it is easier to not serialize events by using the field specifier for the attribute, i.e. `[field: NonSerialized]` on the event declaration.

Comment: I got the same error and found this page. However, my problem is, as  it turns out, that I added a new class and forgot to add [Serializable] attribute to the class, so that it didn't get serialized correctly in the first place. Then, when it tries to deserialize, I got this error. Once added [Serializable] attribute to the class, everything works fine.